# What makes a material adhesive (or sticky)?

Tags: everyday-life, adhesion

I currently have a bandage on my arm that isn't sticking to me but definitely sticks to itself. It brought up the question:

What makes a material sticky? What's happening on the molecular level? Why do some materials stick to some things better than to others?

Comment: The 3M medical version is described as having a very strong adhesion to the backing material but low to everything else.   http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/mediawebserver?mwsId=66666UgxGCuNyXTtoxftoXfaEVtQEcuZgVs6EVs6E666666--  This is not the same as another interesting material: self-almalgamating tape:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-amalgamating_tape

Comment: Just to check: there's adhesive on the tape? IOW, one side is much more sticky than the other? If you'd make a moebius strip the wrong way around, it wouldn't bond? Those are easier to design, as the designer has freedom to choose both adhesive and substrate.

Comment: @MSalters This particular one is self adhesive both ways, that is, I can flip it over and it will stick to itself the other way.

Comment: @MSalters, I'm going to broaden this to just ask about adhesiveness in general rather than self-adhesiveness in particular.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different types of adhesion. As pointed out by Ryan S. :

Electrical, like when a balloon sticks to your head after a good rubbing. Chemical, like plastic cement will "melt" the plastic pieces to be bonded together. And the most common, physical, which is extremely hard to make an example of without a picture. Therefore, I give you a picture. 
What we have here, is paper. Normal paper. (Thanks for the picture [Arstechnica](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/03/forget-the-watermarks-secure-the-paper/)!)

[image]

Glue, or other adhesive (like gum) can squeeze itself into the spaces between the fibers, and harden. The hardening while in an irregularly shaped form is what makes glue sticky. (That, and some amount of chemical bonding.)
I would think that in a case of a bandage, the electrical adhesion would be negligible. Probably most of the "stickiness" would come from the glue pressing into a crack/ around a hair etc. I would also guess that it would have a fair amount of chemical adhesion, but I would think that that would occur after the bandage had been worn for some time.

Then again, the manufacturers have probably found a formula that gives an extremely "bond happy" substance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesive_bandage

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, new to this forum! Adhesion works a few different ways (these are the most common):
Chemical bonds (super glue or tape)
Mechanically (think Legos or Velcro)
Electrically (think fabric softener sheet stuck to you pant leg)

As far as the bandage that won't stick to your arm: the chemical adhesive probably cannot hold onto the oils on your skin. Does that help?

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? Right now, it doesn't really help one to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: Not to mention you need to explain why the "lego blocks" don't tangle with any other material surface