# What makes silicone sticky?

Tags: electrostatics, material-science, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, adhesion

I've read from [3M's Adhesion Science articles](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/bonding-and-assembly-us/resources/how-does-adhesion-work/) and [this StackExchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/what-makes-a-material-adhesive-or-sticky) that there are three types of adhesion: chemical, physical, and electrostatic.

I'm curious about what makes silicone rubber sticky. My best guess is that it's the electrostatic adhesion? Silicone rubber easily holds to human skin, and it naturally attracts a lot of dust and lint.

Is there any way to amplify that stickiness without adding a chemical adhesive (eg. glue)? Can you strengthen the electrostatic forces somehow?